# Chrome displays JavaScript file in what appears to be Chinese

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

## Screen Shot of Problem

[image: Chrome js file]

### My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
  <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
  <script src="scripts/vendor/require.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

### The js file

```
var d;
```

That is all there is. The file used to be require.js from their main site. But I deleted everything trying to figure out what was going on. I then deleted the whole file and created a new file (with the same name). Could I have changed something with Chrome to make in interpret files this way? I can't reproduce the problem with any of my other projects. I also originally downloaded the file using [jam](http://jamjs.org/). Really I could just start a new project folder and probably solve the problem but I am curious as to why it would do this. Maybe something stupid simple since I am new to this.

Comment: What encoding did you save the file as? What HTTP headers are sent with it?

Comment: I updated the screen shot to include the HTTP headers. And I just saved it again with UTF-8 just to make sure (problem is still there). Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Could it be a Byte Order Mark? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark this is the kind of thing random unicode errors can cause

Comment: @SLaks I was assuming only the js file might have the encoding error when I first read your comment, but it was the index.html file. If you submit an answer I will accept yours since you were right about the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was a encoding problem with my index.html file (I re-saved the file with UTF-8 encoding and the problem went away).  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer. You helped me solve a similar issue I had using PSDeploy to perform a transform on a HTML file on an automated build server:  Turns out that where I was issuing my final `Out-File` statement, I had to include the flag `-Encoding "utf8"` in order for the output to have the correct encoding on the build server.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the master file and the linked script file must have the **same encoding**, otherwise Chrome browser will not be able to load it correctly.

For example, if the html file is encoded in UTF-16 LE and the javascript file in UTF-8, then Chrome will silently assume that the javascript file is also in UTF-16 LE and fails to load it.

You can add a charset attribute to the script element to hint about encoding and in such case, Chrome will load it correctly:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Test</title>  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's definitely not a chrome problem (look at `content-length: 6` ) did you try restarting your server after saving the file?

Comment: you're right. I didn't mean a problem with chrome. I meant more  in the sense: could I have changed a setting or something to make chrome interpret files in this way? I'll change my wording a bit in the question.