# JavaScript code translated into Chinese and gives VM180:1 Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, html, css, utf

JavaScript code doesn't work in chrome. I gives me an error:

> VM180:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

When I see on console in chrome, all my code is written in Chinese, but in my code file, it is written in English.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTFuc.png)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqs.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="slides">
        <li class="slide showing">Slide 1</li>
        <li class="slide">Slide 2</li>
        <li class="slide">Slide 3</li>
        <li class="slide">Slide 4</li>
        <li class="slide">Slide 5</li>
    </ul>
    <button class="controls" id="previous">Previous</button>
    <button class="controls" id="next">Next</button>
    <script src = "app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* essential styles:these make the slideshow work
*/

#slides {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
/*non-essential styles:just for appearance; change whatever you want*/

.slide {
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

.slide:nth-of-type(1) {
    background: red;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: orange;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(3) {
    background: green;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(4) {
    background: blue;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(5) {
    background: purple;
}
```

**JS file**

```
"use strict";
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;

function nextSlide() {
    goToSlide(currentSlide+1);
}

function previousSlide() {
    goToSlide(currentSlide-1);
}

function goToSlide(n) {
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentSlide = (n+slides.length)%slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}
var next = document.getElementById('next');
var previous = document.getElementById('previous');

next.onclick = function() {
    pauseSlideshow();
    nextSlide();
};
previous.onclick = function() {
    pauseSlideshow();
    previousSlide();
};
```

Comment: wrong character encoding? e.g. utf-16

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other text file, `.js` files have specific encoding they are saved in. This message means you are saving the `.js` file with a non-`UTF8` encoding (probably ASCII), and so your non-ASCII characters never even make it to the disk.

While saving files from your Text Editor, you'll have to change the encoding of the file, choose **UTF-8** without saving a *Byte Order Mark (BOM)*.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9853620/1939163
Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14902390/1939163